# Is there a better way to simulate mouse movement in selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium

Websites with good security are detecting the clicking with just driver.find_element(By.XPATH, button).click().

Is there a way to simulate my mouse movement like a real human?
I need to move around the page a bit before doing a specific action..
And I don't want to move my actual cursor...is it possible?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896) discussion help you?

Comment: can u try to just do driver.find element and then click the button manually with your mouse and see if it works? if it doenst, we may have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's gonna work because I have to move the cursor through the browser window to get to that button and websites know that that is human movement. They probably detect the linear movement that selenium does when interacting withing a browser....

Comment: Do you mind sharing the website link?

Comment: The website is tiktok